# ngrx How to subscribe to action in component or subscribe to state

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

i put object to state by action via effect:

```
{
 field1: 'value1',
 field2: 'value2',
}
```

but then, i adding new field (via effects, after server's response) and redux looks like:

```
{
 field1: 'value1',
 field2: 'value2',
 newField: 'this is new field'
}
```

In component i need to get just final, last state.
How i can do it ??? 
Subscribe to store and get state just when "newField" already in place.

```js
@Effect()
  initializeMain$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofAction(AppInitializeAction),
    map(action => {
      const obj = {
   field1: 'value1',
   field2: 'value2',
   }
      return new InitializeObjAction(obj);
    }),
  );

  @Effect()
  addNewFieldToState$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofAction(InitializeObjAction),
    map(action => {
      const newField = {
   newField: 'This is new field'
   }
      return new addNewFieldAction(newField);
    }),
  );
```

I've heard about combine reducers...but i do not know how to use it.
Reducers:

```js
   @Action(InitializeObjAction)
 initialize(state: IAppState, action: InitializeObjAction) {
    return { ...state, mainState: action.payload };
   }
   @Action(addNewFieldAction)
 addNewField(state: IAppState, action: addNewFieldAction) {
    return {
      ...state,
      mainState: {
        ...state.mainState,
        newField: action.payload
      }
    };
```

In component i need:

```
this.store.select(storeStateWithNewField).subscribe.....
```

Comment: you can add a selector in the reducer for the same and get it from the store rather than getting the whole store and filter

Comment: could you give me an example please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RxJS [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator :

```
this.store.select(storeStateWithNewField)
.pipe(filter(_ => _.newField !== undefined))
.subscribe...;
```